# Why is a variable's value not updated as expected before being output?

Tags: javascript

I know I should not submit a question with this title, but I am really confused by the following code. anyone can explain why the last line print 1?

enviroment: chrome 80.0.3987.163

```js
console.log(foo) // undefined
if (true) {
  foo = 1
  console.log(foo) // 1
  function foo() {
    console.log("a")
  }
  console.log(foo) // 1, function foo is hoist
  foo = 2
  console.log(foo) // 2
} else {
  function foo() {
    console.log("b")
  }
}

console.log(foo) // 1, why?
```

if remove the function declaration, it's OK.

```js
console.log(foo) // undefined
if (true) {
  foo = 1
  console.log(foo) // 1
  foo = 2
  console.log(foo) // 2
} else {
  function foo() {
    console.log("b")
  }
}

console.log(foo) // 2
```

Comment: Since `ES2015` function declarations are block scoped.

Comment: The function declarations should be hoisted the first line of the `if block`, then `foo = 1` should assign `1` to the block local `foo`, the last line should print `undefined`, but the `foo` is `1` in global.

Comment: If you add `"use strict"` at the beginning of your file and after that `var foo;`, then it behaves as you expect. Must be some kind of backward compatibility rule. You should in general use `"use strict"` so that all rules apply.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after the function declaration inside the if block, the JS engine thinks that you're referring to the function. If you change the function name it should work properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(foo) // undefined
if (true) {
   var foo = 1;
    console.log(foo, 'foo1') // 1
    function foo2() {
        console.log("a")
    }
    console.log(foo, 'still foo1') // 1, function foo is hoist
    foo = 2
    console.log(foo, 'foo2') // 2
} else {
    function foo() {
        console.log("b")
    }
}

console.log(foo) // 1, why?
```

This first foo is the global scope

after the function with the same name, it was identified as a local scope i.e it become a local scope within that function but if you change the function name everything should work normal i.e foo will now be of value 2

Comment: "it become a local scope within that function..." What function are you referring to?

Comment: within the foo function

Comment: The question is not how to solve a problem, but to explain why `foo` in the last line is `1` instead of `undefined` (or maybe `2`), because the function `foo` inside of the `if` block should be hoised to the top and of the block so all `foo` within that block should refer to the `foo` of that function.

Comment: @nitrocode I'm not sure I understand; nothing it declared or defined in the local `foo` function.